# SAS Computab Output with Multiple Columns

Tags: sas

Does anyone know how to make SAS output `Proc Computab` output into excel or `rtf` output with multiple columns. It puts all the output into one column, which I have to use `"Text to Columns"` to get into multiple columns. Any idea on how to fix tis issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ODS HTML, but specify a filename which ends with '.xls' as opposed to '.htm'.

Excel will read the HTML code into rows & columns.

e.g.

```
/* this is really a HTML file, drop it into a text editor to see! */
ods html body = "c:\HTML.xls" ;

proc computab ....

run ;

ods html close ;
```